# Can anyone hep me to find the probability of the following question please?

Tags: probability, self-study

The organizers of a banquet at a restaurant have ordered 10 place settings, but they have invited 13 people. Past experience indicates that 15% of the people who are invited independently decide not to come.

If more than 10 people come there will be a surcharge of $100 times the number of additional people. What is the expected surcharge?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, if this is homework, please add the self-study tag.

Comment: Isn't expected value (surcharge) probability * value? So, p(x=11)*100 + p(x=12)*200+p(x=13)*300 ?

Comment: I got $121.11 using: sum(dbinom(c(11,12,13), 13, 0.85) * c(100,200,300))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 15% of people invited don't show up, the probability a guest will show up is 1-.15 = .85. The expected number of guests out of the 13 invited follows the binomial distribution: $$\binom{13}{n}(1-.85)^{13-n}\cdot 0.85^n $$

For n in (11, 12, 13) we have p(x = n) in (0.294, 0.277, 0.121) and the penalty we pay is \$100, \$200, \$300. This gives $\textrm{expected surcharge} = 0.294*100+ 0.277*200+ 0.121*300 = \boxed{\$121.11} $